# Stackpanel Thickness Animation

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is thickness animation for stackpanel in WP7?
I want to change margin of stackpanel, but Visual Studio can't find this type of animation. How to do it?
Also question, how to set this animation to VisibilityChanged EventTrigger?

PS: I tried to set animation in XAML.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have got code similar to http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92928/Thickness-animation-in-Silverlight-Margin-Padding to work in WP7.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for this wrapper, but it is for Silverlight 5.

Comment: I used TranslateTransform to change X and Y coordinates.

Comment: That article was published "9 Jul 2010"... so I'm pretty sure it's not for Silverlight 5.